# AutoIt v3: _IENavigate + _IELoadWait Not Working as Expected?

Tags: browser, navigation, automation, autoit

This code is supposed to open a new browser set at "www.website.com," submit a username and password, wait for the page to load after being submitted, navigate to a new page, and inject a javascript code into the address bar.

My current results from this code are opening a new browser set at "www.website.com," submit a username and password. The submit works, then **from here, the code breaks and instead of navigating to the next page (page2) it just hangs.**

Even when I add an ignore command to the _IEFormSubmit($oForm) I can't get my page to navigate to the next page.

```
#include <IE.au3>

#RequireAdmin

Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.website.com")
;_IELinkClickByText($oIE, "Sign In") ;Optional
Local $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "regular-user-login-form")
Local $oText = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "log")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oText, "username")
Local $oText = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "pwd")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oText, "password")
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)

_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.website.com/page2/")

Send("{F4}javascript:check_in();{ENTER}")
```

Please for the love of god, what am I doing wrong.

Edit: I've also changed the _IEFormSubmit($oForm) to another javascript submit and I can still log in without any problems, but once I reach that next page I can't use _IENavigate, so the problem has to lie there.

Comment: I'm still looking for help with this problem - I've found a couple of solutions that take a different route than using _IENavigate, but I'd really like to be able to use that particular bit of code if at all possible. At the very least, I'd like to understand why it's problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have automated so many different pages and sometimes the script gets stuck on _IEFormSubmit for no reason. That's an AutoIt bug.

Her's a quick fix for that

```
_IEFormSubmit($oForm, 0)
_IELoadWait($oIE, 1000)
```

Your code should be:

```
#include <IE.au3>

#RequireAdmin

Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.website.com")
;_IELinkClickByText($oIE, "Sign In") ;Optional
Local $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "regular-user-login-form")
Local $oText = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "log")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oText, "username")
Local $oText = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "pwd")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oText, "password")
_IEFormSubmit($oForm, 0)
_IELoadWait($oIE, 1000)

_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.website.com/page2/")

Send("{F4}javascript:check_in();{ENTER}")
```

Onetime, I tried to report two bugs to autoit forum, but the guys who are there are pretty frustrated fellas. So, now when I find one, I just solve it my way.

Off topic:

When dealing with objects you should know of another bug

```
If $oInput.outertext = "Continue" then ...
```

The above code will sometime fail even if the outertext matches.
This is solved using, use

```
If $oInput.outertext == "Continue" then ...
```